# Magento won't create minified JS files

Tags: magento2, javascript, production-mode, minified-js

I switched my Site to production mode and enabled JavaScript minification, bundling and concatenating in the backend, expecting Magento to correctly create the `.min.js` files - It won't, though. First I thought there might be something wrong with the webserver config, but looking at the filesystem, there simply were no minified versions of the scripts.

I did the following (in vain) to resolve:

- Deploy static content again
- Run upgrade and Di:compile commands
- Flush all caches
- Clean the `var/cache` and `pub/static` directories
- Cleared the *JavaScript/CSS-Cache* in admin
- Run `bin/magento deploy:mode:set production` again

So I switched back to non-minified, non-bundled scripts, resulting in Magento loading an insane amount of individual files, taking ages for it.
How do I get this (absolutely basic) feature to work? *grumble *

I know this gets asked pretty often here, but most of the questions deal with files being written to disk, incorrect permissions or development mode.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?  I have a similar issue where .min.js are not generated however only on one store front for me.

Comment: No, I decided to take the performance toll - I can't bill my customer hours with no results, so I decided to leave it as it is. Honestly, Magento is the worst product I ever had to work with. So sorry , I'm of no help here...

Comment: ha i'm having a nightmare with it also so many bugs and issues that are slowing me down wish i just stayed with Magento 1. Thanks for getting back to me tho ill post here if i get to the bottom of my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Once you switched to production mode, did you happen to run the setup and compile commands?

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

This probably could have been posted as a comment on your question, but I don't have that permission yet, sorry.

Comment: Yep, I did. Sorry, forgot to mention in the list above.